# Disable automatic doubling of "\" character Python 2.7 - re2 bug

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I am trying to build a regex with Python 2.7.

I have this code:

```
expression = u"(|\s|[.!?\\-])+?(\b%s\b)(\s|[.!?\\-]|\Z)+?" % term
```

If my term is "technologies" is expect to get:

```
(|\s|[.!?\\-])+?(\btechnologies\b)(\s|[.!?\\-]|\Z)+?
```

However, what I get is this:

```
(|\\s|[.!?\\-])+?(\btechnologies\b)(\\s|[.!?\\-]|\\Z)+?
```

The \ character in \s and \Z get doubled. Before, instead of an unicode string, I used a r string (r"..regex...") and my \b character used to get doubled as well. Now, without using r"", \b is as I expect it, however, \s and \Z still gets doubled.

Additionally, I wrote an ugly hack, `expression.replace("\\\\", "\\")` in the hope of getting rid of the extra slashes. However, it doesn't work.

How can I get rid of the extra slash?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Adding r makes things worse.

Input 1: `expression = u"(|\s|[.!?\\-])+?(\b%s\b)(\s|[.!?\\-]|\Z)+?" % term`

Output 1: `(|\\s|[.!?\\-])+?(\btechnologies\b)(\\s|[.!?\\-]|\\Z)+?`

Input 2: `expression = r"(|\s|[.!?\\-])+?(\b%s\b)(\s|[.!?\\-]|\Z)+?" % term`

Output 2: `(|\\s|[.!?\\\\-])+?(\\btechnologies\\b)(\\s|[.!?\\\\-]|\\Z)+?`

**EDIT 2:**

I found the bug, it wasn't related to the double . I will detail after I finish here. It has to do with re2.

Answer (score 4):

add r at the beginning of string
so

```
expression = r"(|\s|[.!?\\-])+?(\b%s\b)(\s|[.!?\\-]|\Z)+?" % term
```

As r keyword at beginning of a string tells python interpreter that treat this as a raw string. So all escape chars are treated as regular chars

Comment: This is worse, it doubles all my \ characters. I'll illustrate in an edit.

Comment: @RandomGuyqwert I believe the default output of the variable by ipython is escaping the content. Try printing it: `print r"(|\s|[.!?-])+?(\b%s\b)(\s|[.!?-]|\Z)+?" % term`

Comment: @RandomGuyqwert remove the extra backslashes in your expression as outlined by Robin. As now escape chars are treated as regular chars